# How to run user installed app with uwsgi

Tags: uwsgi

How to run an app installed with `pip install --user` ?

suppose I install this package as the Unix user `py_user` :

```
pip install --user pkg
```

and that I can import the app as following :

```
from pkg.ws import app
```

(suppose `app` a flask app)

How do I setup uwsgi (write an ini file) so that it can be run with `uwsgi pkg_app.ini`, and then, it could run as a vassal in emperor mode) ?

(it should run with `uid=py_user`, `gid=py_group`)